# Writing unit tests for a function instrumented with opentelemetry javaagent

Tags: java, open-telemetry

I have added opentelemetry **javaagent** to a project and used it to instrument the project. Is there a way to test the instrumentation(for example created spans) in the unit tests?

Lets say this is my whole project code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(hello());
    }

    @WithSpan("hello")
    private static String hello() {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

How can I test that calling the `hello()` function creates a `hello` span?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To write unit tests you can access the exported spans with `AgentTestingExporterAccess`. You need to import these packages:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.opentelemetry.javaagent</groupId>
    <artifactId>opentelemetry-testing-common</artifactId>
    <version>1.23.0-alpha</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.opentelemetry.javaagent</groupId>
    <artifactId>opentelemetry-agent-for-testing</artifactId>
    <version>1.23.0-alpha</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

A simple unit test can look like this:

```
import io.opentelemetry.api.trace.SpanKind;
import io.opentelemetry.javaagent.testing.common.AgentTestingExporterAccess;


import static io.opentelemetry.api.common.AttributeKey.stringKey;


import io.opentelemetry.sdk.trace.data.StatusData;


public class MainTest {
    @Test
    public void testHello() {
        AgentTestingExporterAccess.reset();
        Main.hello(); // This a function that creates a span
        var spans = AgentTestingExporterAccess.getExportedSpans();
        assertEquals(spans.get(0).getName(), "hello");
        assertEquals(spans.get(0).getKind(), SpanKind.INTERNAL);
        assertEquals(spans.get(0).getStatus(), StatusData.unset());
        assertEquals(spans.get(0).getAttributes().get(stringKey("service.name")), "search");
    }
}
```

Please note that to be able to use `AgentTestingExporterAccess`, you need to run your tests with the javaagent too. If the java agent is not attached when running the tests, you will get an exception from `AgentTestingExporterAccess` like this:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Error accessing fields with reflection.
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
...
```

Another way of doing this is to write a mock server and capture the spans. Opentelemetry has an example [here](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-docs/blob/cef845752aa39ead1eb23223420c3b58d1874907/telemetry-testing/src/test/java/io/opentelemetry/example/telemetry/ApplicationTest.java)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can also set up OTEL to log the traces somewhere useful, like a temp file. You can set it up via a system property or environment variable as described here:
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/blob/main/sdk-extensions/autoconfigure/README.md#logging-otlp-json-exporter

BTW I work at [digma.ai](https://digma.ai) and we are developing a free IntelliJ plugin that has a really cool feature for enabling/disabling OTEL for tests and analyzing the results. You can also use it to validate which traces are being recorded by test runs.